# On GitHub, can I fork just a wiki?

Tags: github, wiki

If I fork repository `joe/foo`, and it has a Wiki, I won't get the wiki. Right now I'm just interested in forking the wiki to add pages to it.

1. Is that possible without forking the repository?
2. If not, is it possible at all?

Comment: Related: [How can I make a pull request for a wiki page on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10642928/4561887)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't fork it directly on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), but you can get [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) access to it by going into the Git access tab of the wiki and you should be able to fork it on your local machine and edit it as much as you want (and even get updates to it!)

Comment: But I guess there's no way to have it show up in that fork graph thingy?

Comment: I don't think so, wiki's are separate from the actual repo.

Comment: Well... there is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080848/how-do-i-clone-a-github-wiki

Comment: If I can't fork it, I also can't send pull request on wiki pages right?

Comment: @MattS., [In't there an easier way to do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9452695/632951)

Answer (score 28):

In June 2019, here's how I did that:

1. Fork a repo. The wiki is not forked automatically. So your fork will have empty wiki.
2. Create a wiki in the forked repo. Just create an empty Home page or whatever.
3. Clone the git repo of original wiki: `git clone https://github.com/org-a/project-x.wiki.git`
4. Assuming your forked repo now sits in `https://github.com/org-b/project-x`, add the new remote to the wiki repo: `git remote add fork https://github.com/org-b/project-x.wiki.git`
5. Do the force push to overwrite your wiki with the original `git push -f fork master`

Great. Now you have forked a repo and its wiki.

(By the way, Github should do this automatically, right?)

Comment: So as a result, you have two separate repo: one for code and one for wiki, but you can't create a pull request for the wiki repo, can you?

Comment: No, I just did this only to discover there is no way to contribute my Wiki changes. WTF, Github?

Comment: Well, does not work any more, because authentication does not work. you have to access the repo via SSH in order to be able to write to it from console. But access to WIKI.git only goes through HTTPS. Am I right or does anybody know a solution?

Comment: It works using HTTPS and personal access tokens as described here https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: Your answer is fine. I've upvoted it. But, for beginners who need *a lot* more detail, they can [check out my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77294223/4561887). Note also that I've inverted it. Instead of cloning the upstream repo but pushing it to your new wiki repo like you've done, I clone the new wiki repo and fetch the upstream wiki repo, hard reset onto it, then force push. This way they end up with _their own_ _"accompanying wiki git repository"_ stored locally which they can use to edit their own wiki.

Answer (score 5):

You are able to just clone a Wiki from a repo now. You can find a tab called `Git Access` under `Wiki` tab of a repo.

But you still can not fork a wiki without forking its project repo.

Answer (score 3):

> On GitHub, can I fork just a wiki?

Yes, but it requires using `git` from the command-line. If on Windows, you will need the Git Bash terminal which comes with [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/), to run `git` commands at the command-line. On Mac or Linux, use your regular terminal.

Below, I present three options to fork a wiki.

*The following concepts apply to any of the major git-based hosting platforms, including GitHub and Atlassian BitBucket. My tests and screenshots are from GitHub. I imagine that the same concepts would also apply to GitLab and others, but I have not tested it. This practice of making the "wiki" into a separate git repo from your main git repo is pretty common among the big code hosting platforms.*

### Background knowledge

Don't skip this part. You need to understand some things.

##### Git vs GitHub; branches and repos:

Just like every git branch is actually made up of up to 3 branches, which confuses the heck out of everybody (see [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely/23961231#comment107954274_23961231), and the answer above it), every GitHub repository is actually made up of **up to 2 *git* repositories**, which also confuses the heck out of everybody. Remember: GitHub is *not* git! Git is a command-line version control tool. GitHub simply *uses* git. GitHub can do whatever the heck they want. They could store 1000 git repositories for every GitHub repository if they wanted.

So, the two underlying *git* repositories in a single *GitHub* repository are:

1. The main git repository you generally push and pull to, and fork.
2. The secondary git repository used to store *the wiki pages* only, *so long as* you have created at least one page on the wiki.

##### Example

Here is an example. We will reference this image:
[image]

1. The **main GitHub repo:** https://github.com/nicolargo/glances

   1. Click the green "Code" button shown in the image above to view the *git* URLs to it.
   2. **Git URLs:**

      1. HTTPS: `https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.git`
      2. SSH: `git@github.com:nicolargo/glances.git`
      3. These Git URLS are *not* intended to be accessed in your browser! They are not webpages. They are intended to be used only at the command-line with `git` commands. They are the git *remote* server URLs.
2. The main GitHub repo's **corresponding wiki repo,** which exists since this *GitHub* repo has at least one wiki page: go to https://github.com/nicolargo/glances --> click the "Wiki" tab at the top, as shown in the image above.

   1. Direct link to the wiki: https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/wiki
   2. In the bottom-right of the wiki page, see the "Clone this wiki locally" section to view the *git* HTTPS URL to it:

      1. [image]
   3. **Git URLs:**

      1. HTTPS: `https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.wiki.git`
      2. SSH: `git@github.com:nicolargo/glances.wiki.git`

         1. **Important!**

            1. This URL is not shown in the image just above, but it does work and exist. All you do is take your main git repo URL, remove the `.git` extension, and replace it with `.wiki.git`.
            2. Prefer the HTTPS git URLs for read-only access to someone else's git repos, and prefer the SSH URLs for read/write access to *your own* git repos.
      3. Again, these Git URLs are *not* webpages! They are for use only at the command-line with `git` commands. They are the git *remote* server URLs to these git repositories, for use from the command-line.

##### Git limitations

**None**. A git repository is a git repository is a git repository. You have *two* git repositories above. Their HTTPS URLs are `https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.git` and `https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.wiki.git`. You can do *anything you want* to it via `git` commands at the command-line. Again, in Windows, use the Git Bash Linux-emulation terminal, and on Linux or Mac, use your regular terminal.

##### GitHub limitations

GitHub only supports forking the main repository (at git remote server HTTPS URL `https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.git`, in this case). It does *not* support forking the wiki repository. It also only supports Issues, branch protections, pull requests, etc., on the *main repository.* It does not support them on the wiki repository. For the wiki repository, just editing a wiki page in the GitHub web editor online creates a commit and pushes automatically. There is no pull request, no branch protection, no Issues, etc.

If you want all of those features, you need to put your wiki pages *into* the main repository as markdown pages within it. That's fine, but then you have a more cumbersome process for community members to update the wiki pages, because now your "wiki" pages will be in the main, highly-regulated git repository, rather than in the unregulated wiki git repository. GitHub *intentionally* makes the wiki repository easy to modify, but also unprotected.

##### Let's define some terms

1. Let's call `https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.git` the *"main git repository"*.
2. Let's call `https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.wiki.git` the *"accompanying wiki git repository"*.
3. If you move the contents of `https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.wiki.git` into `https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.git`, which you can do via git at the command-line by the way, let's call that concept *"wiki pages in your main git repository"*, or *"markdown pages in your main git repository"*.
4. If you delete `https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.wiki.git` and move it into its own stand-alone main GitHub repository, then you will now have the ability to fork it, create Issues, have pull requests, etc. Let's call that concept a *"main git repository which is used as a wiki"*.

In my answer below, I will cover forking 1, 2, and 4 above in 3 separate ways:

1. [most common] How to fork the *"main git repository"* and its *"accompanying wiki git repository"*.
2. How to copy an *"accompanying wiki git repository"* into a new *"main git repository"* to create a *"main git repository which is used as a wiki"*.
3. How to fork an *"accompanying wiki git repository"* into the *"accompanying wiki git repository"* of any other *"main git repository"*.

Here we go:

### Option 1 [most common]: fork the *"main git repository"* and its *"accompanying wiki git repository"*

Let's fork the `glances` repository and its accompanying wiki repository.

1. In a web browser, log into GitHub.
2. Go here: https://github.com/nicolargo/glances
3. Click the "Fork" button at the top:

   [image]

   On the page that opens, click "Create fork".

   My username is [ElectricRCAircraftGuy](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy).

   I now have this fork of glances, with my username in the webpage URL: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances

   If I click the green "Code" button --> "SSH" tab, I can see my git SSH URL: `git@github.com:ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances.git`. My HTTPS URL is `https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances.git`.

   In my terminal on my computer, I can clone the repo:

   ```bash
   # What I will run to clone my own repo with read/write permissions
   git clone git@github.com:ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances.git

   # What others can run to clone my repo with read-only permissions
   git clone https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances.git
   ```

   [x] Forking the *"main git repository"* is now done. But, forking the *"accompanying wiki git repository"* is not done yet.
4. Try to clone the *"accompanying wiki git repository"* to prove it does *not* exist yet.

   I know from experience that GitHub does not fork the wiki repository when you fork the main repository. I also know that the *"accompanying wiki git repository's"* git URLs will be as follows. Simply remove `.git` from your *"main git repository's"* git URLs, and add `.wiki.git` instead:

   *"accompanying wiki git repository"* git URLs:

   ```bash
   # What I will run to clone my own accompanying wiki git repo with 
   # read/write permissions
   git clone git@github.com:ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances.wiki.git

   # What others can run to clone my accompanying wiki git repo with 
   # read-only permissions
   git clone https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances.wiki.git
   ```

   So, if I run `git clone git@github.com:ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances.wiki.git`, I'll get this error, as expected, since my forked repo does not have an *"accompanying wiki git repository"* yet:

   ```bash
   $ git clone git@github.com:ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances.wiki.git
   Cloning into 'glances.wiki'...
   ERROR: Repository not found.
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.
   ```
5. Click the "Wiki" link at the top of your new, forked repo. You'll see this:

   [image]

   Click the "Create the first page" button. In the web editor that opens, just click "Save page" in the bottom right:

   [image]

   I now see this, and the "Clone this wiki locally" section is now visible in the bottom-right:

   [image]

   GitHub has now created a nearly empty *"accompanying wiki git repository"* which we can work with.
6. Clone your empty *"accompanying wiki git repository"*:

   ```bash
   # What I will run to clone my own accompanying wiki git repo with 
   # read/write permissions
   git clone git@github.com:ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances.wiki.git

   # What others can run to clone my accompanying wiki git repo with 
   # read-only permissions
   git clone https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances.wiki.git
   ```

   This works fine now. I run:

   ```bash
   git clone git@github.com:ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances.wiki.git
   ```

   This creates a new `glances.wiki` folder on my computer, with the `.git` folder in it, of course, plus a single `Home.md` markdown file in it, which contains the Wiki home page you see online at https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances/wiki.
7. Command-line work: fork the original glances *"accompanying wiki git repository"* into your new, empty *"accompanying wiki git repository"*

   ```bash
   # cd into your new, empty accompanying wiki git repo
   cd glances.wiki

   # view your git remotes; the "origin" one is the one you just cloned
   # from your own new _"accompanying wiki git repository"_
   git remote -v

   # Add the original glances repo as a remote repo, and call it "upstream"; 
   # use the HTTP git URL for read-only access
   git remote add upstream https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.wiki.git

   # prove you've added it
   git remote -v

   # fetch the upstream _"accompanying wiki git repository"_ you just added
   git fetch upstream

   # view your remote git branches you just fetched, and make note of the 
   # "upstream" one. I see the following:
   #       origin/HEAD -> origin/master
   #       origin/master
   #       upstream/master      <==== the upstream branch we need later
   git branch -r

   # Ensure `git status` is clean, and that you don't have any local, 
   # uncommitted changes to your _"accompanying wiki git repository"_. 
   # It should say: "nothing to commit, working tree clean".
   git status

   # back up your branch in case you royally screw this up
   git branch my_backup_branch

   # hard reset your branch to the upstream you just fetched, which is called
   # "upstream/master" in my case, as shown above
   git reset --hard upstream/master

   # List files to see you now have all pages from the upstream wiki
   ls

   # Force push it to yoru own _"accompanying wiki git repository"_
   git push -f  # see WARNING WARNING WARNING below; never do this again on
                # your _"accompanying wiki git repository"_.
   ```
8. Go back to your wiki page and refresh the page: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances/wiki

   And voila! I now see this:

   [image]

   ...just like the upstream wiki page, here: https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/wiki
9. Done. I hope you thoroughly understand now that a GitHub *"accompanying wiki git repository"* is just another regular git repo like any other git repo! Just use the command-line.

   Note: I use the command-line to write and edit my wiki pages too. Then I push them. I hardly use the online wiki editor on GitHub.

   WARNING WARNING WARNING: **never** ever force push `git push -f` again, or else you permanently wipe other peoples' changes that they make via the web interface, and since people editing the wiki via the web interface don't have the "*accompanying wiki git repository*" cloned locally, they can't recover their changes, ever. You will erase their work forever.

   So, if you edit the wiki via the command line, and `git push` fails, NEVER use `-f`. Instead, pull the latest changes, merge them with yours, and `git push` again cleanly.

### Option 2: copy an *"accompanying wiki git repository"* into a new *"main git repository"* to create a *"main git repository which is used as a wiki"*

*I'm not going to include so many details from this point forward. The above instructions should be enough to get you going as a beginner.*

This option is most useful if you want to have a professional wiki page with branch protections, Issues, pull requests, etc. This is what I use at work to create wikis for my team. In this case, the "wiki" is just a regular git repo which we use as a wiki by storing a ton of linked markdown files in it.

1. Go to GitHub in a browser and make a new repo. I'll call mine `glances_wiki`. It's here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances_wiki
2. Now do everything locally from the terminal:

   ```bash
   # Clone it locally, using the SSH git URL
   git clone git@github.com:ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances_wiki.git

   # cd into it
   cd glances_wiki

   # add the original _"accompanying wiki git repository"_ of the glances repo
   # as an upstream to your new _"main git repository"_
   git remote add upstream https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.wiki.git

   # fetch the upstream _"accompanying wiki git repository"_ you just added
   git fetch upstream

   # hard reset onto it; WARNING WARNING: hard reset will wipe local changes
   git reset --hard upstream/master

   # force push it to your own _"main git repository"_; WARNING WARNING: 
   # this permanently wipes changes in your remote "origin" on github
   # for this repo
   git push -f
   ```
3. Done. Check it out: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances_wiki

   The "Home.md" page is now the main page of this *"main git repository which is used as a wiki"*. Rename that file to "README.md" if you want it to show up automatically on the website when you view the repo in a browser on GitHub.

   Ironically enough, my *"main git repository which is used as a wiki"* also now has a wiki page, so *technically* you can have a wiki of your wiki. Here is that page. It's empty: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/glances_wiki/wiki

### Option 3: fork an *"accompanying wiki git repository"* into the *"accompanying wiki git repository"* of any other *"main git repository"*

This option is most useful if you just want to copy the *"accompanying wiki git repository"* of one repo into the *"accompanying wiki git repository"* of another repo, while keeping the their corresponding *"main git repositories"* separate and distinct.

1. For this demo, I'm creating a nearly-empty repo called `wiki_copy_demo`, here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/wiki_copy_demo
   This is basically just Option 1 again, but into a different GitHub repo instead of the forked one.
2. Add at least one page to your destination Wiki--same as before in Option 1. Here's mine: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/wiki_copy_demo/wiki.
3. Now, let's copy the glances upstream *"accompanying wiki git repository"* into the *"accompanying wiki git repository"* of this new `wiki_copy_demo` repo:

   ```bash
   # Clone your new _"accompanying wiki git repository"_ locally, using the 
   # SSH git URL
   git clone git@github.com:ElectricRCAircraftGuy/wiki_copy_demo.wiki.git
   # cd into it
   cd wiki_copy_demo.wiki

   # add the original _"accompanying wiki git repository"_ of the glances repo
   # as an upstream to your new _"accompanying wiki git repository"_
   git remote add upstream https://github.com/nicolargo/glances.wiki.git

   # fetch the upstream _"accompanying wiki git repository"_ you just added
   git fetch upstream

   # hard reset onto it; WARNING WARNING: hard reset will wipe local changes
   git reset --hard upstream/master

   # force push it to your own _"accompanying wiki git repository"_; 
   # WARNING WARNING: this permanently wipes changes in your remote 
   # "origin" on github for this repo
   git push -f
   ```
4. Done. The Glances wiki is copied into mine. See here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/wiki_copy_demo/wiki

### See also

1. My answer to [How can I make a pull request for a wiki page on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56810747/4561887)

Answer (score 2):

If you're making your own wiki that others would be interested in forking, you could do something like we did for the [RailsConf 2012 wiki](https://github.com/newhavenrb/railsconf2012/wiki).

We made [a local clone of the wiki](https://github.com/newhavenrb/railsconf2012/wiki/_access) and then did `git push --force` to the "code" repository.  It gets a little out of sync, but that's [easy to rectify](https://github.com/newhavenrb/railsconf2012/blob/master/script/update).

Answer (score -3):

As of 30 March 2016, you can just create a new "Home" Wiki page and the wiki pages for the forked repository will show up in your fork once the new Home page is created (provided that you have forked the parent repository).

Comment: Note that it will just say a 'Home' page already exists when you try creating one and pull in the wiki repository from the original project. It kinda looks like a bug to be honest. It just 'notices' there already is a wiki when you try to create a page.

Comment: At the time of this comment, this answer doesn't work.  The [About GitHub Wikis](https://help.github.com/articles/about-github-wikis/) page uses the [Netflix/Hystrix wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki) as an example. I can access that repo and wiki. I forked the repo to my account. In my fork the wiki was empty, as expected. As this answer suggests, I created a "Home" wiki page.  GitHub created it without comment/error. Afterwards, the wiki in my fork contained only the new Home page and no others. This answer is wrong.