# Git - Pushing code to two remotes

Tags: git, github

I have **two** remote git repositories. `origin` and `github`

I push my branch `devel` to both repositories.

```
git push -u origin devel
git push -u github devel
```

But then, when I do. `git push` It would only get pushed to `github`.

Is there anyway I can set up my two remotes, so that I can push changes to both repositories with one command ?

Comment: See also [Pro Git: 9.5 Git Internals - The Refspec - Pushing Refspecs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec#Pushing-Refspecs).

Comment: I did vote to reopen this question. It's is not a duplicate of the one referenced in the close reason. This one asks specifically how to push to multiple repos. While the other question mentions both pull and push, the accepted answer doesn't cover pushing to multiple repos - one could improve it though.

Comment: My use case specifically needed it to be such that I only push to both repositories, but I only pull from one of them.

So if I only had the answer from the question linked, I wouldn't have been able to solve my issue.

Answer (score 892, accepted):

In recent versions of Git you can add multiple `pushurl`s for a given remote. Use the following to add two `pushurl`s to your `origin`:

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin git://original/repo.git
git remote set-url --add --push origin git://another/repo.git
```

So when you push to `origin`, it will push to both repositories.

<s>**UPDATE 1**: Git 1.8.0.1 and 1.8.1 (and possibly other versions) seem to have a bug that causes `--add` to replace the original URL the first time you use it, so you need to re-add the original URL using the same command. Doing `git remote -v` should reveal the current URLs for each remote.</s>

**UPDATE 2:** Junio C. Hamano, the Git maintainer, explained it's how it was designed. Doing `git remote set-url --add --push <remote_name> <url>` adds a `pushurl` for a given remote, which **overrides** the default URL for pushes. However, you may add multiple `pushurl`s for a given remote, which then allows you to push to multiple remotes using a single `git push`. You can verify this behavior below:

```
$ git clone git://original/repo.git
$ git remote -v
origin  git://original/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git://original/repo.git (push)
$ git config -l | grep '^remote\.'
remote.origin.url=git://original/repo.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Now, if you want to push to two or more repositories using a single command, you may create a new remote named `all` (as suggested by [@Adam Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26235/adam-nelson) in comments), or keep using the `origin`, though the latter name is less descriptive for this purpose. If you still want to use `origin`, skip the following step, and use `origin` instead of `all` in all other steps.

So let's add a new remote called `all` that we'll reference later when pushing to multiple repositories:

```
$ git remote add all git://original/repo.git
$ git remote -v
all git://original/repo.git (fetch)               <-- ADDED
all git://original/repo.git (push)                <-- ADDED
origin  git://original/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git://original/repo.git (push)
$ git config -l | grep '^remote\.all'
remote.all.url=git://original/repo.git            <-- ADDED
remote.all.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/all/* <-- ADDED
```

Then let's add a `pushurl` to the `all` remote, pointing to another repository:

```
$ git remote set-url --add --push all git://another/repo.git
$ git remote -v
all git://original/repo.git (fetch)
all git://another/repo.git (push)                 <-- CHANGED
origin  git://original/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git://original/repo.git (push)
$ git config -l | grep '^remote\.all'
remote.all.url=git://original/repo.git
remote.all.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/all/*
remote.all.pushurl=git://another/repo.git         <-- ADDED
```

Here `git remote -v` shows the new `pushurl` for push, so if you do `git push all master`, it will push the `master` branch to `git://another/repo.git` only. This shows how `pushurl` overrides the default url (remote.all.url).

Now let's add another `pushurl` pointing to the original repository:

```
$ git remote set-url --add --push all git://original/repo.git
$ git remote -v
all git://original/repo.git (fetch)
all git://another/repo.git (push)
all git://original/repo.git (push)                <-- ADDED
origin  git://original/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git://original/repo.git (push)
$ git config -l | grep '^remote\.all'
remote.all.url=git://original/repo.git
remote.all.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/all/*
remote.all.pushurl=git://another/repo.git
remote.all.pushurl=git://original/repo.git        <-- ADDED
```

You see both `pushurl`s we added are kept. Now a single `git push all master` will push the `master` branch to both `git://another/repo.git` and `git://original/repo.git`.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: If your remotes have distinct rules (hooks) to accept/reject a push, one remote may accept it while the other doesn't. Therefore, if you want them to have the exact same history, you'll need to fix your commits locally to make them acceptable by both remotes and push again, or you might end up in a situation where you can only fix it by rewriting history (using `push -f`), and that could cause problems for people that have already pulled your previous changes from the repo.

Comment: It seems like `git remote set-url --add --push all git://another/repo.git` might be more sane.  That way you can still push to upstream and origin but 'all' is a special remote used for both remotes.

Comment: This is insane. Why would anyone ever want functionality like this? First add the Master, then override the Master with the Backup, then add the Master in again? Crazy-pants. A lesson in not overriding verbs. `--add` means ADD, not REPLACE.

Comment: @AJB: It's in fact adding a new pushurl. The thing that confuses us is that by having a pushurl, the default URL is no longer used for pushes - which I sincerely disagree with.

Comment: @AdamNelson oh, I agree! Just updated the answer to include your suggestion. Thank you! :-)

Comment: I have a problem that 2 repos that I am pushing have different proxy settings. So when I have proxy defined for remote, it will fail, because there are now 2 push repos in my single remote. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jaanus Sure - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35456245/298054 - Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Awesome guide. I used this to setup 2 push urls as I wanted to push my code to 2 different origins.

Comment: I'm running git version 2.15.1 currently, and this didn't work for me until I omitted the `--add` flag. It seemed to then get past any errors, and once a push url was in my config as a result of this, I could use the command above to my heart's content (with `--add` and `--push`)

Comment: How do i remove one of them again?

Comment: Hi @jweyrich, I tried and set up everything but I still can only push to the first repo. For the second I am getting the error: ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com

Comment: @Roxana are you trying to push -f (or —force)? Looks like the 2nd repo has a protected branch, which rejects overwriting history, or existing commits.

Comment: Many thanks @jweyrich, you are right. The 2nd repo had an additional commit.

Comment: if i have azure and GitLab's how i can do pull and push code both repo on local single repo ?

Comment: [@CodeWizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755598/codewizard) your edit to the example seems to be a mistake. The paragraph above it says `you can add multiple pushurls for a given remote`. If you change the remote name, you're adding a push URL to a different remote, while my example was showing how to add multiple push URLs to the same remote.

Answer (score 110):

To send to both remote with one command, you can create an alias for it:

```
git config alias.pushall '!git push origin devel && git push github devel'
```

With this, when you use the command `git pushall`, it will update both repositories.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the branch an argument in that command ?

Comment: You can pass using bash function: `git config alias.pushall '!f() { git push origin $1 && git push github $1; }; f'`

Comment: Even though this works, it feels a bit hacky. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290113/git-pushing-code-to-two-remotes#answer-14290145) seems like the nicer solution.

Comment: *pros:* easier, a bit more portable; *cons:* does not work with `--tags`, less scalable (say 4 repos)

Comment: One alias for multiple projects doesn't work well if you push different projects to different places.

Comment: @WilliamSeitiMizuta With your command I get "Syntax error: ";" unexpected".

Comment: I had to manually edit .git/config and write `pushall = "!git push origin $1; git push github $1 #"` in the `[alias]` section. The `#` was to ignore the rest of the line.

Comment: this is a much better solution

Comment: Or just add an alias to your .zshrc or .bashrc with the custom command.

Something like direnv is also nice as you can add aliases based on the repo.

Comment: Example


`export GIT_GPA_REMOTES=("origin" "bb"); gpa(){ for i in "${GIT_GPA_REMOTES[@]}"; do; git push $i $@; done };`

Comment: While I liked the idea of configuring a remote to have multiple pushurl entries, I found that in practice only one remote's tracking branch (call it the the primary) was updated when I pushed to that multi-url remote and I had to `git fetch secondary` for `refs/remotes/secondary/<branch>` to be updated, making this approach the only real "one-command push" for me.

Comment: Update: I was surprised that nobody else had mentioned the above issue, then I encountered [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785549/able-to-push-to-all-git-remotes-with-the-one-command#comment22163951_5785618), which does.