# Mirroring git branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, gitolite, mirroring

I have a private repository on my own server hosted with gitolite. Now I want to opensource it on github, but still have one private branch.

All howtos are implying that I want to mirror whole repo with all tags and branches. But is it possible to have only common branch?

So, all I want is to keep my private branch up-to-date with public, but with some specific changes (these changes are even in separate catalog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [configure your local repository to push to both remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290113/git-pushing-code-to-two-remotes).

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin git://github/repo.git
git remote set-url --add --push origin git://gitolite/repo.git
```

Then you could push the public branch to origin.

You could maintain your private branch separately, and push that to the gitolite remote.

```
git remote set-url gitolite git://gitolite/repo.git
```

You are free to merge or cherry pick differences between the branches.