# Github: readonly access to private repo for distributed deployment to customer devices

Tags: github, deployment

I have a private repo that needs to be deployed to many IoT devices (RasPi). I'd like to be able to `git pull` via `cron` job. I'm wondering how to manage the read-only access to the repo:

- access to code is not a consideration as it will be available on the device anyway
- deploy keys don't seem to work as they grant *write* access

I'm thinking about using a dedicated github user with read-only access for this purpose. Are there other or better options?

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem, [Github Organization](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations) provides a read-only access.

Comment: Unfortunately organizations require username and password which I would need to make public then- also granting access to e.g. issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there other or better options?

Another (similar to a dedicated user) is to have a mirror of your private repo in a public repo.

That public repo can be only accessible by its owner (the "dedicated user"), and is read-only for the rest of the world.

One way is to [set up a webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) in order to listen to the push event and push to the mirror.

But if you are the only contributor to the private repo, it is easier [to directly push to both remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290145/6309) (the private and public ones).