# Loop through JSON data and run the job for each set of inputs

Tags: json, github-actions

I have an `input.json` file that looks like below

```json
{
  "appname": "apple",
  "category": "fruit",
  "buildapp": [
    {
      "workdir": "work1",
      "tesdir": "test1",
      "setdata": {
        "set1": "value1",
        "set2": "value2"
      }
     },
     {
      "workdir": "work2",
      "tesdir": "test2",
      "setdata": {
        "set1": "value3",
        "set2": "value4"
      }
   }
  ]
}
```

I have to read it in GitHub Actions and loop through each buildapp section and print all the "key" and corresponding "value" pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [matrix strategy](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs) to define inputs for your publishing step.

In this case, the workflow can be divided into two separate jobs: the first job should provide the output with a tags array and the second job should use this output as a matrix input:

```yaml
name: 'Loop JSON'

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  read-json:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      json-content: ${{ steps.file.outputs.content }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Read the file
        id: file
        uses: juliangruber/read-file-action@v1
        with:
          path: ./file.json

  loop-json:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: read-json
    strategy:
      matrix:
        app: ${{ fromJSON(needs.read-json.outputs.json-content).buildapp }}
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ matrix.app.workdir }}
```

Resulting workflow:

[image]

In this example, I used the [Read file](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/read-file) Action to read the json file from my repository.

Each job will print the value of the `workdir` node. Following this example, you can access the other values.

The file:

```json
{
  "appname" : "apple",
  "category" : "fruit",
  "buildapp": [
    {
      "workdir": "work1",
      "tesdir" : "test1",
      "setdata" : {
        "set1": "value1",
        "set2": "value2"
      }
    },
    {
      "workdir": "work2",
      "tesdir" : "test2",
      "setdata" : {
        "set1": "value3",
        "set2": "value4"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Similar cases with the `matrix` usage:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62953566/7328018
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74855626/7328018