# Custom post-receive hook with gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, webhooks

I am trying to set up a custom post-receive hook using gitlab

I am following their documentation 
[here](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/hooks/custom_hooks.html#custom-git-hooks)

I have an executable post-receive file in the custom_hooks folder with the following code:

```
 !/bin/bash
 echo "post-receive firing | wall
 git pull
```

If I run this file with:

```
 ./post-receive
```

It works fine. It does not appear to fire at all when a push is made to the gitlab repo.

This is the first time I have ever tried web hooks of any kind so I am a little lost.

a) I have the above script on my remote webserver, inside the .git/custom_hooks folder, is this correct?

b) Do I need to do anything in the repo?

c) In the documentation, it specifies I should set permissions on the file so it is owned by the 'git' user. I have no git user on the webserver... all other git related files are owned by my user or root.

So assuming I am doing something completely wrong here, can someone please put me out of my misery and suggest a sane way to auto push to a web server whenever I push to gitlab from a local machine. I feel like I have spent some time looking for a way to do this and solutions seem to be complete overkill (cronjob running every few seconds...) or like the above, do not seem to work. Or at least I seem incapable of making them work.

Surely this is a straightforward task...

Comment: Thanks for edit, but it's not what I ask for. Actually, my hook is working. What I don't know is how to pull the files from git server (gitlab's repo) and copy to my apache www folder. I have nothing to do with online versions, everything is in my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> on the file so it is owned by the 'git' user. I have no git user on the webserver... all other git related files are owned by my user or root.

That is because oyur webserver is a client of the GitLab server.
The [documentation you reference](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/hooks/custom_hooks.html#custom-git-hooks) is for configuring a GitLab server (adding a post-receive hook to a GitLab repo). [Hence the '`git`' user, which is the default one on a GitLab server](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5c6d83b8e772dedb753336d83783123e166fbe40/config/gitlab.yml.example#L45-L46).

But if you are pushing to gitlab.com, you wouldn't add directly a hook.

You would need to declare a **[web hook](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/web_hooks/web_hooks.html)**, which would then send back a JSON message that you [can listen to in order to trigger another action](https://serverfault.com/a/463510/783).

If you are the only one to push, [you could simply push to multiple repos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290145/6309). No hooks involved there, client or server.
But that would be a local setting valid only for your local cloned repo.

Comment: "You would need to declare a web hook, which would then send back a JSON message that you can listen to in order to trigger another action."           I did look into that but am I correct in thinking I need to then write my own custom tool (in whatever language) to sit there on some port and process the incoming hook? That seems overkill when all I want to do is auto push to a web server via the gitlab repo

Comment: Yes, à web hook implies a listener. The quick fix workaround remains to push to 2 repos at once.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow following steps

1. Go to your git sever
2. Find hooks using following command
   find / -xdev 2>/dev/null -name "hooks"
3. Select and go to your respective project hook folder.
4. open post-receive file in edit mode (http://www.wikihow.com/Create-and-Edit-Text-File-in-Linux-by-Using-Terminal)
5. put your logic here. if want to execute url u can do it in following way

require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse("YOUR_URL")
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

Hope, this will help you