# Can I push a local repo to two remote repos?

Tags: git, bash, heroku

I want to use these bash function to push my local repo to two remote repos, but I'm not sure if this will work.

```
p_foo_0() {
  git add -A .
  git commit -m "test"
  git push origin master
  echo "success"
}

p_foo_1() {
  git add -A .
  git commit -m "test"
  git push heroku master
  echo "success"
}
```

Comment: Here is one way to do it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290113/git-pushing-code-to-two-remotes

Comment: And here was the old way to do it, which also contains an updated answer similar to above - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your remotes using:

```
git remote set-url all --push --add <first-repo>
git remote set-url all --push --add <second-repo>
```

Now you can use:

```
git push all master
```

to push to both repos