# sanity check for git deployment, staging and production on same server, existing code

Tags: git, deployment, staging

Say I have a single server which has an existing production site and its staging site.

Now I create a bare repo at `~/` which has a `hook/post-receive`

```
#!/bin/bash
# post-receive
# deploy production and staging to vhost dirs

# Directory we are deploying to. Should be the directory where the repo's root .gitignore would exist in.
PRODDEST="/path/to/destination/of/production"
STAGDEST="/path/to/destination/of/staging"

while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    # Grab the name of the branch that was pushed.
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)

    if [ "master" = "$branch" ]; then
        echo "Master push, deploy production..."
        GIT_WORK_TREE=$PRODDEST git checkout -f master
        GIT_WORK_TREE=$PRODDEST git clean -fd

    elif [ "develop" = "$branch" ]; then
        echo "Develop push, deploy staging..."
        GIT_WORK_TREE=$STAGDEST git checkout -f develop
        GIT_WORK_TREE=$STAGDEST git clean -fd
    fi
done
```

By pushing from local to either remote branch, the code in the respective folder gets updated on the server. This works, but I've been too cautious, since I've only done this on dummy production and staging folders.

Now what if I want to use this on my existing production site, without moving its location? (After changing the `PRODDEST` and `STAGDEST` locations)

I go into my production root folder where all the existing code is and run `git init`, `git add .`, `git commit -m "initial commit"`, `git add remote hub ~/hub.git` and `git push hub master`. (Also add a bitbucket origin and push to that).

I'll add a rewrite for the `.git` folder in `.htaccess`

When testing this out I got messages asking me to pull from hub first instead of push to hub as there was code in hub but not in the production folder.

Is this a sane way to do it without messing up the existing site? Anything else I should beware of?

Comment: If I understand correctly, by doing this anytime anyone pushes anything new in development the real production site will get updated. That's a very bad idea

Comment: On my pc if I run `git push origin develop` then the hook will checkout to the staging site. When I run `git push origin master` the production code gets updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks largely correct (see below), and this bit:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
```

is a nice trick to avoid depending on ref format, but I'd probably cheat and write the loop interior more like:

```
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    case $refname in
    refs/heads/master) deployto $PRODDEST prod master;;
    refs/heads/develop) deployto $STAGDEST dev develop;;
    esac
done
```

with a deployto() function that does the checkout (and if you like, `git clean` too, though it seems this step should not be required).  See below what the middle argument is for.

Here's where "largely correct" comes in, and might be why you need the `git clean`.  Git keeps, in the `index` file, a cache of how the target directory (`$PRODDEST` or `$STAGDEST`) looks.  It doesn't expect the target to change from one `git checkout` to the next.  It uses the previous cached state to optimize the process of updating the work-tree to the new state.  If staging and production are sufficiently different, git won't get the "previous state" right when the last checkout was to the other tree.

I think setting a per-destination index file is the "right way" to deal with this.  There are lots of ways to structure it but here's a lightly tested method that uses that middle argument:

```
deployto() {
    GIT_WORK_TREE=$1 GIT_INDEX_FILE=$PWD/$GIT_DIR/$2.index git checkout $3
}
```

(the `-f` should not be required here either, unless for some reason the web server modifies the destination directory).

Comment: thanks, very detailed. I'm still grappling with my basic workflow as my idea doesn't work. As a summary, can you confirm: 1. create bare repo on server that has this post-receive hook 2. create repo in server prod codebase and push to bare repo (plus also push to somewhere like a bitbucket repo) 3. clone bare repo locally 4. push from local to bare repo, which updates the prod code base?

Comment: just to deal with production for now, I'll tackle the staging part once I have this tied down

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your intent is with part of part (2) above.  (1) is necessary since you generally only want to push to bare repos (git is growing more ability to push to "regular" repos these days, with new receive modes, but this is the traditional setup and works), and (3) and (4) are the usual work-flow, but why create a new repo on the server? (Maybe I'm misreading that part.)  But otherwise this looks right to me.

Comment: ok thanks, I added 2. because it's where the code for the existing live site is. This is what everything hinges off, it's the starting point for everything.

Comment: but I could copy all the existing production files to local and start from there. step 2. also served as a way of pushing to bitbucket, so I'll need to figure out a way of pushing both to the bare repo and to bitbucket from local without 2.

Comment: ok, so I just copied tarred the live code to local, and set up a push command which goes to both bitbucket and the remote bare repo thanks to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14290145/3779933

Comment: Aha, interesting, I didn't know git would push to multiple URLs with a single remote.  (I'm not sure it's a good idea in the first place, I might have implemented it as a group, a la fetch groups, but as long as it's there...).