# Connecting a branch inside a repository with another github repository

Tags: git, github

Lets say I have two repository `A` and `B`. Repository `A` has a branch called `b`.

I want to *connect* `A.b` with `B`. By *connect* I mean, whenever I `push` to `A.b` the same content will also get pushed to `B`. And whenever I `push` to `B` the same content will also get pushed to `A.b`

This may lead to redundancy of data, but I am simply asking is this possible in GitHub and if possible how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article might help out - [Git - Pushing code to two remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290113/git-pushing-code-to-two-remotes)

I've never tried it myself, but it seems like one of the answers provided there is what you're trying to do (add multiple pushurls).