# Pushing code to multiple remotes

Tags: git, git-remote

I'm new to posting/commenting on StackOverflow so I couldn't comment in this link: [Git - Pushing code to two remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290113/git-pushing-code-to-two-remotes/14290145#14290145)

I noticed that the order of the push URLs matter. In the case of:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
Fetch URL: git://original/repo.git
Push URL: git://another/repo.git
Push URL: git://original/repo.git
```

It will push to `another` first. But if that `another` is inaccessible, the push will fail and git won't bother pushing to `original`. My workaround was to switch the Push URL manually in `.git/config` so that `original` comes first (assuming more accessible).

Is this scheme reliable for working with multiple branches? I'm using `original` as my main for fetch/pull, and `another` for backup. Or will I be better off with using alternative methods (i.e. two remotes with two pushes)?

Comment: Use multiple remotes, it's much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

When you are pushing to a `remote`, Git will try pushing to all `ref-urls` aliased by the `remote` name, till it encounters a unsafe exit situation. If you need different URLs to refer to two different functional copies of your data, you should consider using two different `remote` aliases/names.

Doing so will only cost you one more push command, but gives you the added advantage of being able to choose **what** commits to push to **where**.