# How to manage syncing between two remotes having same code?

Tags: git, github

I will be having two git repositories:

1. Github
2. OpenShift

Both are going to have the same content. I just have to make sure they are in sync.

I currently have my `origin` renamed to `github` so that by doing `git push github master`, I push to `github` and for `openshift` I am planning to have a remote `openshift` that points to `openshift` git repository.

This way I can push codes separately:

- `git push github master`
- `git push openshift master`

Currently after running `git remote -v` I get:

```
$ git remote -v
github  https://github.com/animesh/asdf.git (fetch)
github  https://github.com/animesh/asdf.git (push)
github  ssh://xxxxx@asdf-animesh.rhcloud.com/~/git/asdf.git (push)
```

I added an upstream path to the `openshift` repo so that as soon as I push in `github`, the content is also pushed into `openshift` repo but I am finding it hard to manage.

How can I maintain two remotes in the way I want to?

Comment: Can't understand the problem. You can push to both individually, and together as well. What is your desired result?

Comment: I will have the changes on `github`'s master branch and I want the changes to be committed to both the remotes.

Comment: Ah! I get it now. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290113/git-pushing-code-to-two-remotes

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you added two push URLs to your remote but you want to have two remotes to which you can and have to push individually.

So what I'd recommend is, rename your `github` remote to `both` and then use `git remote add` to add a `github` remote and again to add an `openshift` remote. This way you can push to one remote or to both remotes with one command, depending on which remote you push to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) to automatically push to the remote `openshift` if the push to github is OK. The post-update hook is a script which runs after the push command. It seems to be what you are looking for.

**Edit** : I saw Vikram Tiwari comment and he is right, the link [Manage multiple remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514618/how-to-manage-syncing-between-two-remotes-having-same-code) seems a better / easier solution.