# How to setup Sourcetree to deploy to Heroku and Bitbucket?

Tags: git, sourcetree

I have setup a repository that points to heroku. In the "Optional Extended Integration" I have chosen "Bitbucket Server" as the host type, Host URL is set to "https://bitbucket.org" and the username is set to my username. Now whenever I commit a change to heroku I would like to commit that to Bitbucket as well. Unfortunately this does not seem to work with the setup I mentioned above. Is there anything I am doing wrong here? I am using SourceTree for Mac.

Comment: When you click on `Repository > Repository settings`, does it show two remotes on the "remote repository path" list?

Comment: I am pretty new to git. Yes, it shows 2, because I added two. One for origin and one for bitbucket. When I push my changes I push them to all repositories. Still not 100% sure though if this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: What are the remote names shown on that screen?

Comment: origin and bitbucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get two remotes in sync, the most common way to achieve that is to push your changes to both:

```
git commit -m <msg>
git push origin <branch>
git push bitbucket <branch>
```

On SourceTree:

- Click on "Push"

  [image]
- Select the remote on the dropdown, then select which branch you want to push, and click on OK.

  [image]
- Repeat the process to the other remote.

Anternatives are:

- Setup multiple urls to a remote - [This SO answer can give you details on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290113/git-pushing-code-to-two-remotes)
- Setup commit hooks to automatically push commits to a secondary remote everytime push them into your default remote.