# setup remote heroku repo on source tree

Tags: heroku, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to use Source Tree to push to Heroku. I've installed the Heroku CLI, so in order to clone an existing repo from Heroku, I just need to login through the terminal and it works, but if I have to push, I always get a permission denied.
So I'm wondering if I need to setup something in Source Tree as I've done for my Github repo. but in settings > account... I can only pick Github or Bitbucket. So how can I authenticate and push to Heroku?

Thanks

Comment: How did you try? i means commands you used ? Did you tried like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818274/how-to-setup-sourcetree-to-deploy-to-heroku-and-bitbucket) ?

Comment: [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) is steps to setup heroKu

Comment: I only used the Source Tree GUI. Never used the CLI. I did the clone and that was working, but when I pushed it, l always got an error. Cause it was trying to pushing it using my username from github and I didn’t understand where to change this. Anyway, I used the Heroku CLI only for the first auth and thanks to that I could clone, but not push