# Deploy to multiple servers same time

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins, deployment

I have 4 servers, One for load balancing (Nginx reverse proxy) and 3 nodejs (upstream servers).

I want to deploy code from bitbucket to this 3 servers same time, How i can manage it? 
I can install jenkis on each this 3 server and deploy but is there better solution? can i install jenkins on load balancer server and deploy from it?

Comment: Git now supports pushing to more than one repo, see something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290113/git-pushing-code-to-two-remotes

Comment: You can use a master-slave setup in which you push to the master. The master will start 3 slaves jobs (each slave on each server).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write script which will do it for you.
The script can be a shell script of any language or you can use Jenkins to do it for you as well.

You dont need Jenkins on each server, you simply need a git script which will push it to your servers or that your servers will pull the changes form the server.

Comment: So i should write script which will pull the changes from bitbucket, than run several commands (npm install and e.tc.) and put this script on each server and call it manually? am I right? I want manual deployment (not automated after bitbucket push changes)

Comment: Yep, or you can do it with Jenkins as well, its up to you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this is to pick a primary repository you push to, and then to install a hook in that server that automatically pushes all incoming stuff to the other servers.

```
$ cat .git/hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/bash

IFS=' '
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do

  echo "$remote_ref" | egrep '^refs\/heads\/[A-Z]+-[0-9]+$' >/dev/null && {
    ref=`echo $remote_ref | sed -e 's/^refs\/heads\///'`
    echo Forwarding feature branch to other repository: $ref
    git push -q --force other_repos $ref
  }

done
```