# How to connect one code into two git repositories?

Tags: xcode, git

I have an iOS project in my Xcode. I want to push my changes into two separate git repositories. (One is repository in our local network and the other one is a repository in my servers on Internet). Is there any options to connect the code to two repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another remote repo - see [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

```
git remote add otherrepo https://github.com/blabla/blub42
```

Then you can push to it

```
git push otherrepo master
```

Answer (score 0):

As [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290145/6309), you can modify your current remote to push to multiple url:

```
 git remote set-url --add --push origin $(git remote get-url origin)
 git remote set-url --add --push origin /new/url
```

(you need both commands)

Then a git push would push to both urls.