# How to force pull before push

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

Every time I want to push my commits (`git commit -m "message"`, `git push origin <branch>`), I do a pull (`git pull origin <branch>`).
Is there any way to make git do a pull before performing my push? (on the same branch)

Comment: you can create alias for that - in git config file add [alias] mypush = !git pull -r && git push

Comment: but I do not know if you should do that

Comment: doesAirExist && doBreathing

Comment: What is the context for this problem? Are you trying to run this in a script, or just save typing interactively at the command line?

Comment: @merlin2011 If I commit a change without doing pull and my teammate has commited some changes, my code will be auto-merged to his code. I don't want this happen.

Comment: See my answer for how to avoid the merge commit that normally comes from `git pull`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Git way to do this is with [customize Git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

In your case, you will need to go to the `.git/hooks` directory on your repository, and add a file named `pre-push`, which is a script of your choice, e.g. (bash in this example)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "pulling ..."
git pull
```

This script will be called when you do `git push` and before the actual push.

Obviously, this is just a very naive sample, but I hope you get the idea. There are samples in this directory already. Comment if anything still unclear.

Comment: Why exactly is that a "very naive sample", i.e. what *else* should this hook script do besides what's in your answer?

Comment: this is pretty old answer, but I think I meant case specific logic may be added - conditions, flags, etc. the example is straightforward and in real world will probably be more complex (but it doesn't have to)

Comment: this will never gonna work for new branches before they are in remote

Comment: @DAG This is not the situation that Ali Farhoudi mentions when his changes are automatically merged with commits from teammates

Answer (score 11):

Based on the OP's comments, they appear to be trying to avoid a merge commit between their recent commits and the commits on the remote, which is normally generated by a `git pull` when the local and remote histories have diverged.

The explicit way to do this is to first fetch and the rebase, and finally push.

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push
```

A second way to do this is to pass `--rebase` when invoking `git pull`.

```
git pull --rebase
```

Finally, one can make this the default behavior of `git pull` by setting the configuration.

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
```

Answer (score 6):

You actually don't need to pull before pushing: if there are commits on the remote side you don't have locally, the git push will fail with the message message:

```
Pushing to git@yourserver:<user>/<repo>.git
To git@yourserver:<user>/<repo>.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/BigMeanCat/CMDA'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

If you have control over the remote server, you can set there:

```
git config --system receive.denyNonFastForwards true
```

---

More generally, you can [easily define an alias combining both commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290150/6309):

```
git config alias.pullpush '!git pull && git push'
```

If the pull fails, the push won't be executed.

---

Finally, you can combine any sequence of command in a bash script, named

```
git-pullpush
```

(no extension, executable, stored in a folder referenced by the `$PATH`)

It would be a regular bash script (which works even on Windows, since it will be interpreted by the msys bash)

```
#!/bin/bash
# you can add any command you want
git pull && git push
```

And you would call it with `git pullpush` (like an alias)

Comment: Thank VonC. This is very good, but it is not what I wanted. There must be a step to commit and set message for my commit.

Comment: @AliFarhoudi That is why I mention in the script " you can add any command you want". That include any step you need.

Answer (score 3):

When you want `command2` to run if and only if `command1` succeeds(*basically returns 0*), run using double ampersand sign `&&`, sandwiched between them:

```
command1 && command2
```

And, to run `command2` after `command1` succeeds **or even if fails**, run using semicolon `;`:

```
command1 ; command2
```

I have used former one for `git pull && git push` and later one for `git pull ; date`

Comment: Thanks @saurav-sahu. This is helpful but I want to know if there is any way if I forgot to ```pull``` and just ran ```push```, it somehow alert me or run ```pull``` automatically. Currently it merges last commit of others with my commit.

Comment: Ok..I see..I will check and let you know...BTW space-separated alias like `git push` are not supported as per my knowledge.

Comment: `git push` is already going to reject if you are not up-to-date with the remote. Just push. The act of pushing asks whether it is possible to push. If there's a reason why you can't push, you won't be able to push. Then you can worry about what to do.

Comment: yes, git push rejects code but when i pull after rejection, my teammate commit will be merged to my commit.