# branches not showing up in new remote 'gitlab'

Tags: git, gitlab

I added new remote based on some online information that I have collected. My commands are

```
git remote add gitlab  http://ankits@abc.xyz/janedoe/my.git
git push gitlab master -f
```

But when I do

```
git branch -a

*master
sprint_2
sprint_3
remote/gitlab/master
remote/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remote/origin/sprint_2
remote/origin/sprint_3
remote/origin/sprint_1
```

How come I don't see branches sprint_2/3/1 in my gitlab remote?

Comment: You only pushed one branch to the remote *gitlab*, didn't you? You have two remotes linked to your local repo: origin, the remote you already had before, with 4 branches and the new one, where you pushed master branch. Are there supposed to be more branches on http://ankits@abc.xyz/janedoe/my.git? If so, do `git fetch gitlab`

Comment: no..there are no branch in 'gitlabl remote. My purpose for setting up new remote is to use it for Continuous integration/Continuous development using GItLab tools. So every time I push something, it triggers a pipleline on GitLab and run regression.

Comment: Have a look at the `--mirror` option, but be careful it implies the `--force` option.

Comment: so I added mirror option to git remote add --mirror=fetch gitlab <path_to_new_mirror_remote>, but it's not working. Also, when I push changes from local master, it only shows up in origin/master. It's not showing up in gitlab/master.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: Nevertheless if you want to duplicate the repo in GitLab, maybe it's better doing it this way: https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/. Otherwise you only push local branches, except you push explicitly remote branches from origin/*

Answer (score 8):

this undesired behavior probably occur because the current branch has no upstream branch. To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use:

```
git push --set-upstream origin <your-branch-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
git push gitlab master
```

you specifically ask Git to push the `master` branch.

If you wish to push all branches to your new `gitlab` remote you can run [`git push gitlab --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---all):

> Push all branches (i.e. refs under `refs/heads/`); cannot be used with other .

Comment: Thanks Chris! that works! Problem is now if commit and push, my orgin remote branch is also updated, but looks like my new remote branch - gitlab is not updated. What am I missing?

Comment: With `git branch -vv` you can see where a branch is pushed to by default. You can change it with `git branch master --set-upstream-to=gitlab/master`

Comment: Thanks. Can I push upstream to origin/master and gitlab/master

Comment: `git push origin master:master` pushes the local master branch to origin/master `git push gitlab master:master` pushes it to gitlab/master

Comment: @Romeo, if you want `git push` to automatically update multiple remotes you [can configure it to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14290113/354577).

Comment: @Romeo if this worked, consider accepting the answer