# Setting up a git hook to automatically git pull on a remote server

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-16.04, webhooks, githooks

I have a remote ubuntu server that stores the live version of my code from GitHub. Every time I push from my local computer with git, I want the remote server to automatically pull the code. Other guides usually talk about adding a PHP file to a web directory though my server doesn't have a direct HTTP URL or a www directory since it's not used for a website.

I've also tried creating a `post-receive` hook but to no result, I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or not.

**My post-receive file in .git/hooks:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
git --work-tree=/home/folder/anotherFolder/repo --git-dir=/home/folder/anotherFolder/repo checkout -f
```

I'd like to note that I'm also not the only one that will be pushing to the repository, so it should support commits from different devices.

Comment: Is the remote server running a linux variant? Do you have administrative privileges on it?

Comment: So you want to push to Github and have this secondary server do a pull automatically?  Your options are a hook in Github (probably hard if the secondary server can't be reached via Github), or a cronjob that runs on the secondary server.

Comment: The remote server can reach GitHub fine, it's just setting up the hook itself which I'm having trouble with. I don't really want to use a cronjob since it seems inefficient and inaccurate - the pull should occur as soon as the code is pushed.

Comment: Probably your best bet is going to be checking out the webhooks api: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/ .  You can add a webhook to the repo under settings.  All you would need for this is some service running on a static port on your server, accessible to the world, listening for that one POST request from the api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If setting up a **[webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)** listener is not practical for you (like for instance [`adnanh/webhook`](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook)), you can check if can push directly from [your own local repo to two repos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14290113/6309): the GitHub one and the Ubuntu one.
Then and only then your post-receive hook would be activated.