# Pushing a branch to multiple remotes

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push

Provided there are two remote repositories (A, B) and there is a branch master (among others).
The first repository A has all branches and the other one B has to have one only masterB.

How can I push local branch master to both remote repositories with a single "git push" command ?
(mapping A: master->master; mapping B: master->masterB)

---

tried so far:

```
[remote "A"]
    url = <urlA>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/A/*
[remote "B"]
    url = <urlB>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/B/*
    push = master:masterB
[branch "master"]
    remote = A
    merge = refs/heads/master
    pushRemote = A
    pushRemote = B //this overrides the previous push remote; how can I use both ?
```

---

[The reference](https://gist.github.com/rvl/c3f156e117e22a25f242) says that multiple 'pushRemote' entries are possible.

Comment: Could you tell us what you are using this for? If it's for deployment, there are better ways to handle deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Your tutorial does mention:

> Then git allows branches to have multiple `branch.<name>.pushRemote` entries.
>   You must edit the `.git/config` file to set them.

That is not apparent from [`git config branch.<name>.pushRemote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-branchltnamegtpushRemote)

> When on branch , it **overrides** `branch.<name>.remote` for pushing.
>   It also overrides `remote.pushDefault` for pushing from branch `<name>`.
>
> When you pull from one place (e.g. your `upstream`) and push to another place (e.g. your own publishing repository), you would want to set `remote.pushDefault` to specify the remote to push to for all branches, and use this option to **override** it for a specific branch.

So managing that case with a script would be easier than tweaking git config settings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had tackled this with a script, but I was hoping I can achieve this via config so I can use e.g. Visual Studio built-in git support and not to worry about running the script later.  Can you give me an example what should I change in the config above to achieve this ?

Comment: @dajuric You can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290145/6309: this is not specific to *one* branch but could still help.

Comment: Thanks. Seen that; does not allow renaming a branch for another remote-repo. I have upvoted your answer. Many thanks!