# How can I share or link to a GitHub enterprise (university) account repository?

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac, github-enterprise

My university has a custom GitHub enterprise domain, and I have been working on a number of personal/group projects there. However, going for graduate job interviews, it would be handy to share access to these repositories so they can see the commit history/my contributions/etc.

Issue: you need a login to access the enterprise domain. So, is it possible to:

1. Write a hook that would push my work automatically to GitHub.com when I push to GitHub.enterprise.ac.uk?
2. I use SSH with my keys automatically setup to detect which domain to push to, is it possible to push to both?
3. Or is my only option to clone each git and manually push to GitHub.com?

Comment: For the security and safety purpose your organization has this custom repository. Why would you like to breach? and I don't think this access has given to you.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290113/git-pushing-code-to-two-remotes

Comment: @DeskToDevelop I'm not advocating opening up access to the entire university's Git to potential employers. What I would be interested in is a way for me to share my own work from said git with certain people who currently cannot access the domain.

Comment: thanks @duggi, I shall give that a try.