# Is it helpful to think of git syntax as being backwards? (at least for push)

Tags: git

I was reading through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290113/git-pushing-code-to-two-remotes#answer-14290145) answer to a question. I've always worked with only one repository until now so I never thought much about the git syntax but this answer made me realize that git's syntax might be backwards to what's conventional. (at least for the push command)

As I understand it, in the accepted answer, @jweyrich makes a new repository called `all` which acts as a repository except it actually represents two repositories in his example. At the end he writes that we can push what we want to commit to the remote repository with `git push all master`.

If I'm understanding this correctly, git is the only api I know of where you specify `<command> <dest> <source>` as opposed to `<command> <source> <dest>`. Copying files, moving files, etc... Is all done with the latter syntax. Even AWS s3 buckets use the syntax `<command> <source> <dest>`.

Why does git seem to have backwards syntax? Am I one of the few that for whom this wasn't obvious when starting with git?

Comment: It's not backwards. The have-it-all syntax of git-push is `git push remotename source1:dest1 source2:dest2 source3:dest3 ..` ignoring --switches. Note that you can push many branches, and specify different target branch for each of them. For example `git push origin myLocalBranch:targetServerBranch` assuming typical name 'origin' for the remote server. Consider other kinds of 'pushes' to be shortcuts or abbreviations for this long syntax. For example `git push origin :targetBranch` deletes it (no source). Another: `git push origin foobar` - assumes that sourcename=destname, and so on.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl But `mv <src1> <src2> ... <dest>` is also a thing.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl your examples show that git is consistent with itself but it doesn't show that git is consistent with another api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you very often know what `<source>` is. 99% of the time, it's the current branch. So:

```
git push <destination>
```

is much easier to do than

```
git push <destination> <current_known_source>
```

---

I think `git rebase` presents a stronger case, though. To rebase `<source>` onto `<destination>`, I am almost always rebasing the current branch onto `<destination>`. Thus, I save the pain of specifying `<source>` each time:

```
git rebase <destination>
```

Comment: I've never used the first shorthand. That's good to know about

Comment: @financial_physician Even shorter: you can often just do `git push` without any arguments at all since usually you're pushing the current branch (e.g. `master`) to a single remote repository (e.g. `origin`).