# 'Manage Remotes' problem in PhpStorm for Git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to use manage remotes to share my project on Bitbucket and GitHub. But there is a problem. When I add a git link of GitHub to manage remotes section, and then when I click push, GitHub seems but Bitbucket doesn't seem. Screenshots are below.

[image]

[image]

.git config like this:

[image]

If I write Bitbucket to remote in branch section and push again, this time it pushes to Bitbucket. But I want to push both at one time. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git - Pushing code to two remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290113/git-pushing-code-to-two-remotes)

Comment: Thanks for the answer my problem has fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, PhpStorm doesn’t support pushes to multiple remotes.
As a workaround you could set in your config "pushUrl" like this:

```
[remote "github"]
    url = <url1>
    pushUrl = <url1>
    pushUrl = <url2>
```

Or as mentioned in comments, use the following commands:

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin git://original/repo.git
git remote set-url --add --push origin git://another/repo.git
```

Comment: I've added 2 pushUrl to my .git config file as you show and the problem fixed. Thank you so much.

Comment: @emrez It would help the community if you mark this reply as an answer.