# GitHub: Using wiki locally: Error when making initial push to GitHub wiki

Tags: git, github, git-push, wiki, gollum-wiki

I searched this problem many times, but still cannot resolve it.

Say, I fork a repo (let's name it repo1) from user1, and now I would like to fork the Wiki section of that repo as well, [which GitHub won't do for you when you fork the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800999/fork-github-project-with-custom-wiki/33828142#33828142).

I tried these commands:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/user1/repo1.wiki.git
git remote add my-fork https://github.com/myid/repo1.wiki.git
git push my-fork master
```

but the terminal prints:

```
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /3/nw/32/2b/9e/135236793/71478887.wiki.git
```

which means that I cannot successfully push this local wiki to the Wiki section of my forked repo.

Does anyone have ideas about what's wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

You need to create the wiki first in your GitHub repository:

1. Open the following URL in your browser:

   ```
   https://github.com/myid/repo1/wiki
   ```
2. Press <kbd>Create the first page</kbd> and then <kbd>Save Page</kbd> buttons:

   [image: How to create a wiki]

Now you can push (the first push should be with `-f` option):

```
git push -f my-fork
```

Comment: I submitted a github support request to add this info to [github's support page on working with the wiki from the command-line](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally/) as it makes no mention of needing to first bootstrap the wiki page via their web interface.

Comment: I opened a [PR](https://github.com/github/docs/pull/16468) to add this to the Github wiki docs.