# How can I update github wiki pages?

Tags: github

I just forked a repo, and the wiki pages.
On my copy of repo, I updated the wiki pages, and now I would like to create a Pull Request to the original repository, with the updated wiki pages. (I just modified the wiki pages, nothing else.)

I tried to make a pull request, clicking and creating a "new pull request", but it says "There isn’t anything to compare."

How can I PR my wiki changed to the original repository?

Comment: Wikis and their underlying repository are not part of the “real repository”, so you cannot make PRs for it.

Comment: This seems quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642928/how-to-pull-request-a-wiki-page-on-github, no?

Comment: See also https://github.com/FreeCodeCamp/FreeCodeCamp/issues/9085

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are a "marked" a contributor, you likely can't.  According to GitHub

> Wikis can be edited directly on GitHub, or you can work with a text editor offline and simply push your changes. Wikis are collaborative by design. By default, only collaborators on your repository can make changes to wikis, but you can configure this to be enabled for all users on public repositories. [**Source**](https://help.github.com/articles/about-github-wikis/)

So, you **can't** make a PR to change a wiki.  You need to be a collaborator unless the settings are such that anyone can make changes, in which case you can go directly to the wiki and edit it.