# Does GitLab permit wiki merge requests?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, wiki

I know [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com) stores wiki pages in a separate Git repository. How can we create a merge request for the wiki project of my project? Is it possible?

I found a similar question about GitHub:
*[How can I make a pull request for a wiki page on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642928/how-to-pull-request-a-wiki-page-on-github)*, but nothing about GitLab.

Comment: Note there is a 2022 workaround. See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38537453/6309).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2016: [Creating a MR (Merge Request)](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr) requires the name of a project, not of its wiki.

The workaround would then be similar to the one described in your [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11481887/6309)

- having a dedicated repo "project" being a fork/clone of the wiki
- making your MR to this wiki project/fork
- pushing from this fork back to the original wiki repo

---

2022: this is followed by [Epic 7107](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/7107), which refers to [this workaround](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/tpa/team/-/wikis/service/documentation#accepting-merge-requests-on-wikis):

> ### Accepting merge requests on wikis
>
> It's possible to work around the limitation of Wiki permissions
> by **creating a mirror of the git wiki backing the wikis**.
> This way more users can suggest changes to the wiki by submitting merge requests.
>
> It's not as easy as editing the wiki, but at least provides
> a way for outside contributors to participate.
>
> To do this, you'll need to create project access tokens in the
> Wiki and use the repository mirror feature to replicate the wiki
> into a separate project.
>
> 1. In the Wiki project, head for the Settings: Access Tokens page
>    and create a new token with write_repository access
> 2. optionally, create a new project for the wiki, for example called
>    wiki-replica.
>    You can also use the same project as the wiki
>    if you do not plan to host other source code specific to that
>    project there.
>    We'll call this the "wiki replica" in either case
> 3. In the wiki replica, head for the Settings: `Mirroring repositories` section and fill in the details for the **wiki HTTPS clone URL**:
>
>    - **Git repository URL**: the HTTPS URL of the Git repository (which
>      you can find in the Clone repository page on the top-right
>      of the wiki)
>      Important: Make sure you add a username to
>      the HTTPS URL, otherwise mirroring will fail.
>      For example, this wiki URL:
>
>      ```
>      https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/tpa/team.wiki.git
>      ```
>
>      should actually be:
>
>      ```
>      https://wiki-replica@gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/tpa/team.wiki.git
>      ```
>    - **Mirror direction**: push (only "free" option, pull is non-free)
>    - **Authentication method**: Password (default)
>    - **Password**: the Access token you created in the first
>      step
>    - **Keep divergent refs**: checked (optional, should make sure
>      sync works in some edge cases)
>    - **Mirror only protected branches**: checked (to keep merge
>      requests from being needlessly mirrored to the wiki)
>
> When you click the `Mirror repository` button, a sync will be
> triggered.
> Refresh the page to see status, you should see the `Last successful update` column updated.
> When you push to the replica, the wiki should be updated.
>
> Naturally, because of limitations of GitLab, you cannot pull changes
> from the wiki to the replica.
> But considering only a limited set of
> users have access to the wiki in the first place, this shouldn't be a
> problem as long as everyone pushes to the replica.

Comment: There is a Gitlab issue for that: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15504

Comment: @geek-merlin Thank you. I will follow this issue and will update the answer if it is resolved.

Comment: @geek-merlin Note there is a 2022 workaround. See [my edited answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38537453/6309).

Answer (score 0):

I have a more decent approach to accomplish this.

you can utilize git subtree, submit merge request like normal files, and review your code and doc together.
let's say you have a repo tree like this:

```
repo -> doc -> your_markdown_file.md
     -> src
```

use a gitlab runner to do the push job every time you merge your code and doc:

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  
build-doc:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "update doc"
    - git status
    - git checkout main
    - git pull
    - git push git@example.com:test/test.wiki.git `git subtree split -P doc main`:main --force
  only:
    changes:
      - doc/**/*
```