# Duplicating repository on GitHub does not transfer Releases to the new repository

Tags: git, github

I am duplicating a repository on GitHub since the same repository now contains 2 highly incompatible and completely separate projects with no plans of merging. The intended end product is 2 repositories that only contain the branches, wiki pages and other information relative to their respective projects and no reference to the other project.

So far I've done this:

- For the main repository, I followed GitHub's instructions: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository

  - This worked great and the new repository has all the commit history of the first one and every branch is there. I will later purge each repository from respective non-relevant branches.
- For the repository's wiki, I used the previous instructions in the wiki's git repository: [How to pull request a wiki page on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642928/how-to-pull-request-a-wiki-page-on-github)

  - I duplicated the contents of the Wiki with no problem. Later I will make sure only relevant pages are kept on each repository.

I don't have too many problems with the Issues listed on the original repository as they are only a few and they only reference one of the projects.

My problem now is that this process did not copy the Releases completely. I get the list of releases of the original repository on the duplicated one, but they don't contain the release summaries nor the binaries attached to every release on the original repository.

The original repository's Release page looks like this:

[image]

But the duplicated repository looks like this:

[image]

I am thinking about updating every Release manually by copying the release information and binaries one by one, but an automated way would be highly appreciated, either using git or GitHub.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that releases (just as issues) are not concepts that are stored or handled in any way by git, they are entirely GitHub-only concepts. This is why cloning a git repository using the git tools will never duplicate them. Maybe a [repository transfer](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/transferring-a-repository#about-repository-transfers) is actually what you're after?

Comment: Thanks, I thought about transfers, but is there a way to still keep the original repository active? I want to be able to keep both versions active

Comment: I don't know, you'd have to check the docs or ask support for that, sorry.