# How do I clone a GitHub wiki?

Tags: github, wiki, git-clone

How do I clone my GitHub repository's wiki? I know it's saved as a separate Git repository, but I can't remember the path.

I've tried `...reponame/wiki.git` and `...reponame.git/wiki`, but neither are correct.

Comment: That question was actually several questions, one of which got it closed for being off topic. Also, at the time the accepted answer on that question didn't exist. If anything that answer should be marked as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

Append *.wiki.git* to the repository name.

That is, if your repository name was *foobar*:

`git clone git@github.com:myusername/foobar.git` would be the path to clone your repository

and

`git clone git@github.com:myusername/foobar.wiki.git` would be the path to clone its wiki.

Note: You must have at least one page to be able to clone the wiki repo. (via @tobiasz-cudnik)

Comment: Do other users automatically have permission to *push* if they can edit?

Comment: Yes. You can set them to have read access based on whether they're a collaborator, but push permissions require them to be a collaborator. https://github.com/blog/774-git-powered-wikis-improved

Comment: Works with https urls too:
 git clone https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala.wiki

Comment: The obvious followup question is: `Can you clone the github Wiki into the same directory as your repo?` Again followed by: *Can I then do a normal `git push` to that repo?*

Comment: Important note - you have to have at least one page to be able to clone the wiki repo.

Comment: What do we do if the repo owner is not a person but a group of people?

Comment: @not2qubit I would not suggest that as it can lead to corrupted repositories. I usually use submodules to have everything in one place.

Comment: @Martin How would you use a git *submodule* in this context?

Answer (score 14):

You can clone the git wiki using following command.

```
git clone https://github.com/<git-username>/<repo-name>.wiki.git
```

Comment: The full path worked well in VS [Git Changes](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-Community:-Clone-Project-Wiki/1510875#T-N1537827). Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for cloning Github wiki repository is:

```
git clone [RepositoryName].wiki.git
```

If it's a private repository, then you'll prompted to enter your username/password.

Answer (score 1):

The Wiki pages are managed as a repository. So click on your repository, then on the left side click on **Wiki**. Finally on the upper right corner click on **Clone Repository**. There you will clear instructions on how to clone it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can totally use GitHub website to clone a repo wiki onto your github space.

1. click + (plus sign) in upper right corner.
2. click *import repository*
3. enter name of old repo with .wiki between .git and repo name, something like git@github.com:projectx/foobar**.wiki**.git
4. Enter the name of new repo, say fubar_wiki

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the URL to the clipboard, see the below screenshot:

[image: Copy URL of wiki repository]

The address bar in your browser shows the URL of the main repository (number 1). The wiki that belongs to the main repository is a separate Git repository. You can see it by clicking the Wiki tab (number 2). Then you have a button to copy the URL of the wiki repository (number 3).