# github link to wiki page from README

Tags: github

How do I create a link from a README.md file to a Wiki page in github? Every example seems to show linking from one wiki page to another wiki page, or from one README file to another file in the repository.  But none that show linking from one to the other

Comment: You're right. "from one README file to another file in the repository" does work, official ref https://help.github.com/articles/relative-links-in-readmes/ official blog https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files , see also https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/awesome-github-feature-no-excuse-for-not-having-good-docs-anymore/ .

Comment: Insightful about why link from README to wiki is not so desirable: "Sure, you could link out to your wiki — but wiki isn’t versioned along with source code, and you want to link to the version of the docs that go along with the exact snapshot of the source repo you’re looking at. Sure, you could link out using absolute URL hyperlinks — but same problem, you’re always linking to master, when you want to link to the file in the same snapshot the reader is looking at the README in." Source: https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/awesome-github-feature-no-excuse-for-not-having-good-docs-anymore/

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You would have to use an absolute URL as opposed to a relative one.

For example:

```
[Sites Using React](https://github.com/facebook/react/wiki/Sites-Using-React)
```

Comment: ok, thats what I thought - just wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way.

Comment: In the doc linked to by @jmar777, it cautions about using absolute URLs: 
"Users cloning your repository will have a much harder time getting the links to work than expected."

Comment: @DaveSexton That's specifically referring to linking to other files in the repository (which will always be relative to the README). When linking to something external (like a wiki), you want to use absolute URLs.

Answer (score 111):

I just came across this question and saw that this was impossible, but stubbornly kept trying anyway. Good news, because this actually can be done with relative links!

If you look at the documentation for [relative links on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/relative-links-in-readmes/), you can see that it supports `./` and `../` operands.

Given that your README is located at:

`https://github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>/blob/master/README.md`

... and the wiki is located at:

`https://github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>/wiki`

... that means you can just crawl back from the README to the wiki, like so:

`[My Awesome Wiki](../../wiki)`

---

*Update:* As some people have pointed out in the comments (thanks!), please be aware that these relative links will break on clones and forks, so be sure to weigh that into your decision!

Comment: Interesting, but notice that the README.md may be viewed from a local clone instead of the web. In that case, the only thing that works is a link with absolute URL.

Comment: Good point, @StéphaneGourichon, I hadn't considered local viewing of the Readme. Although I suppose if relative links are desired that's an acceptable limitation.

Comment: You can clone the wiki locally as a separate git repo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080848/how-do-i-clone-a-github-wiki

Comment: Word of warning: When viewing single files like a `README.md` and a specific blob for an commit, this won't work.

Comment: As mentioned by Stephane Gourichon, relative links aren't always the way to go. Another example is if you want your package to be installable via a third party open source platform. For Python, this is PyPi. PyPi will load in the description, but all the relative links will be broken. You need to go with absolute URLs in this case.

Answer (score 4):

I am using GitLab. My link to my Wiki page looks like this.

```
Checkout the [Wiki page](/%2E%2E/wikis/Welcome)
```

I tried the other recommendations that are posted here but it kept changing the URL with re-writes that broke the link.

Comment: I couldn't find this anywhere and it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I found that I needed to crawl back 3 levels versus 2 levels as descreibed in jmar777's approach.

When I used

```
../../wiki
```

The link generated was `https://github.com/<username>/blob/wiki`

I needed to use:

```
../../../wiki
```

This generated `https://github.com/<username>/wiki`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on this one, if you want to refer to your repo file from inside wiki use `../../blob/master/`. Combined with the answer from jmar777 this allows to completely integrate code and wiki and remove a need for bloated readme.md.

To make it work locally as well as your file structure would have to be

```
./Wiki/YourWikiRepo
./blob/master/YourCodeRepo
```