# How do I undo deleting a github wiki page?

Tags: github

I deleted a page on a github repo's wiki.

Clicking on the link to the file now brings me to a new edit screen. I thought this might be in my fork of the repo, but following the link in incognito mode on chrome gives me the error that I do not have permission to edit this file (presumably because I am trying to create it and I am not logged in in incognito).

I know you can revert changes in files, but how do I revert deleting a file on a github repo's wiki?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can clone the [wiki repo of your project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15080850/6309), and [restore that page locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14922749/6309).

```
git clone https://myusername@github.com/myusername/foobar.wiki.git
git checkout $(git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- yourPage)^ -- yourPage
```

Then you push back to the wiki repo on GitHub: that should allow it to display your page again.

Comment: In case you need to restore older wiki page, you could run:
`WIKI_PAGE_NAME="Insert name of the page here" git checkout $(git log | grep "$WIKI_PAGE_NAME" -B 4 | head -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}')`