# edit github wikis with emacs like confluence-mode?

Tags: emacs, github, wiki, confluence

I got used to using confluence-mode to be able to open wiki pages hosted on a confluence server using my emacs client locally:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ConfluenceMode

Is there anything equivalent to be able to create/edit wiki pages from a github.com repository in a similar fashion?

The basics of what I usually do are:

1. Setting up my URL:

   '(confluence-url "https://myconfluence.server.somewhere/rpc/xmlrpc")
2. Create/Edit pages from emacs:

   M-x confluence-get-page

From then on, it's like any kind of buffer, but it creates/opens/saves files via xmlrpc.

Anything like that but for github.com wikis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering a GitHub wiki is simply a git repo, you can clone it locally, modify it, make new commits and push back.
See "[How do I clone a github wiki?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15080848/6309)".

With a [package like magit](https://github.com/magit/magit), you can do all that from your Emacs (see [magit documentation](http://magit.github.io/master/magit.html)).
For instance, once the commits are done:

> Typing <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> will only push the current branch to the remote. In other words, it will run `git push <remote> <branch>`.