Is there a way to git clone images uploaded to GitHub wiki?
Is it possible to clone the images uploaded to GitHub wiki?
It is possible to clone a GitHub wiki  as its own repo. e.g. (e.g.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080848/how-do-i-clone-a-github-wiki)
But that repo contains only the markdown files, not the images uploaded to the wiki. The images are stored elsewhere, e.g. reachable via https://user-images.githubusercontent
Is there a way to clone that repo which contains the images?
Here's an example repo with a basic wiki page which contains an image
https://github.com/protobi/wiki-test/wiki
E.g. The image is not stored in the wiki repo, it's stored elsewhere at https://private-user-images.githubusercontent.com/10464727/349218010-d7a321c2-1749-4d9d-9131-585935f4974c.png
(My use case is to make sure that all documentation we created is backed up outside of GitHub and to use GitHub wiki as a basic content management system)

Does Ryan Qs answer here have what you need? On cursory review it seems to. Looks like there is a parallel repo. provisioned for each Wiki.
